# How to save a picture in true grayscale?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, keras

I want to save pictures from MNIST dataset in real grayscale. By "real grayscale" I assume, that if I load the images from my hard disk, and load them to keras, they will have only one channel (not 3). But if I save the images by     `plt.imsave('file.png',train_images[i],cmap = 'gray')`, then load them, they have 3 channels, so my little program with neural network that demands one channel (keras, tensorflow) input doesn't work. Or I want the program to load the images, but I shouldn't say it, that they are grayscale, I want the program to determine this by itself

Comment: Seems like it would be easier to load the images as not-grayscale, and then remove all but one channel after you load them.

Comment: Note that your image *is* an RGB image, it just so happens that all channels are equal. You could probably use Pillow like `PIL.Image.open('image.png').convert('LA').save('greyscale.png')`

Answer (score 0):

You probably know this, but a greyscale image is just a 2D array of numbers, usually in the range [0, 1] or [0, 255]. So you can check if an image is grayscale by checking the number of dimensions: if it has 2, then it's greyscale; if it has 3, then it's colour. (If the last dimension has a depth of 4, then it has R, G, B channels, plus opacity information.)

The problem seems to be that you are applying a colourmap and saving the resulting pseudocolour image with 4 channels (RGBA). I think you have a few options:

- Modify the neural network code to just use one channel of the data you give it. Since you applied a greyscale colourmap, the RGB channels will all be the same.
- Modify the neural network code to accept NumPy arrays instead of images, and use `np.save()` to save the image arrays.
- Save the PNGs in a way that lets you save greyscale images. I recommend `PIL`, used via [`pillow`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Assuming `train_images[i]` is a 2D array with values in [0, 1], you could do this:

```
    from PIL import Image

    # Make it unsigned integers:
    data = (train_image[i] * 255).astype(np.uint8)

    # Make an Image object and save it:
    Image.fromarray(data).save('test.png')
```

Comment: It's hopeless... every couple of weeks someone wants to feed an image into some neural network, instead of using the array directly... you can't help them.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest :) I guess sometimes people pick up a script which just expects things a certain way and trying to edit it is too intimidating.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I need to exactly a program that works through command line, and it should work with both 3- and 1-channel images, and the input is the directory of files, so I can't just use arrays

Comment: @number73 We've all been there. I modified my answer a bit to cover more options.